# Method not found error when inheriting abstract method in Perl OOP

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, abstract

I have a subclass that calls a method from a superclass. The method in the superclass uses a method that is defined in the superclass as abstract (not really abstract) but implemented in the subclass.

For example:

```
package BaseClass;

sub new
{

}
sub method1 {

    return someAbstractMethod();
}



sub someAbtsractMethod
{
     die "oops, this is an abstract method that should " . 
         "be implemented in a subclass" ;
}
1;

package SubClass;

sub new
{

}

sub someAbtsractMethod
{
     print "now we implement the asbtract method";
}
1;
```

Now when I do:

```
$sub = new SubClass();
$sub->method1();
```

...it calls the abstract message and I get the specified error message. If I took off the abstract method from the super class and just leave the implementation in the subclass, It does not recognize the method and I get subroutine abstract method not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, you need to tell the subclass what its parent class is.  You also probably need to setup your constructors to pass through to the parent class.  There were also a few misspellings in there.

```
package BaseClass;

sub new {
    bless {} => shift;
}
sub method1 {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->someAbstractMethod();
}


sub someAbstractMethod
{
     die "oops, this is an abstract method that should " . 
         "be implemented in a subclass";
}


package SubClass;
use base 'BaseClass';

sub new {
    shift->SUPER::new
}

sub someAbstractMethod
{
     print "now we implement the asbtract method\n";
}


package main;

my $obj = BaseClass->new;

eval {$obj->method1(); 1} or warn $@;

my $subobj = SubClass->new;

$subobj->method1();
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't set up an IS_A relationship between the parent and child classes.

You can do this with the [`base`](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html) pragma as Ivan suggests, or you can manipulate the `@ISA` array.  Or you can use the [`parent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) pragma.

#### @ISA:

```
package SubClass;
our @ISA = qw( BaseClass );
```

#### [`parent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html):

```
package SubClass;
use parent qw( BaseClass );
```

By the way, don't use the indirect object syntax ever.  To call your constructor do:

my $foo = SubClass->new();

Also, it looks like you aren't using the [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragmas.  Do so.  Always.

Finally, if you have multiple packages in one file, it is helpful to enclose each package in a block.

Check out [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) and [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html), they are handy OOP tutorials in the perldoc.

**Update:**

I just noticed that your method calls are broken. You need to find the invoking class or instance in each method.

```
package BaseClass;

sub new { bless {}, shift; }  # horrible constructor - do not reuse.

sub abstract { die "The present situation is abstract"; }

sub method { my $self = shift; $self->abstract; }


package SubClass;

our @ISA = qw( BaseClass );

sub abstract { print "It's alive\n" );
```

In the script:

```
my $obj = SubClass->new;
$obj->method;

my $base = BaseClass->new;
$base->method;
```

Definitely read the tutorials I linked to. They will help you.

Comment: "By the way, don't use the indirect object syntax ever."  Can someone elaborate on the reasoning for this?

Comment: @MrD, the main problem is that it is ambiguous and can easily lead to the wrong function/method getting called.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955172/what-is-indirect-object-notation-why-is-it-bad-and-how-does-one-avoid-it/32955275#32955275

Answer (score 3):

Your fundamental problem is that you're not using method calls at all. Had you done

```
sub method1 {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->someAbstractMethod();
}
```

in the base class (and assuming inheritance was set up properly) then things would work. But when you write `someAbstractMethod()` that's not a method call, it's a function call, so it's resolved immediately at compile-time, without any regard for polymorphism (what the type of the object is).

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting out with Perl OO dont forget to check out [Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/about.html). See also [Moose::Manual::Unsweetened](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Manual::Unsweetened) for a comparison of Moose with regular Perl 5 OOP style.