# Input array in constructor - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, constructor

I am currently creating a class in Perl that looks like this:

```
sub new{
   $class = shift;
   $self = {
     #Member Variables
     server => shift,
     type => shift,
     domains => shift
   };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}
```

I want the domains to be an array with multiple variables. How would I differentiate an array from a normal variable when using shift? I am trying to input the array like this:

```
 my $var = new class("server",1,(1,2,3));
 my $var = new class("server",1,[1,2,3]);
```

Neither of these work when trying to iterate through the array doing:

```
 for $i ($self->{domains}){
     print "$i\n";
 }
```

Comment: Especially when using object-oriented Perl, you ***must always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl source file, and declare each variable using `my`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments are passed to a function as a list of scalars, and your first invocation is just

```
my $var = new class("server",1,1,2,3);
```

A hash value need be a scalar, so you need an anonymous array there

```
domains => [ LIST ];
```

So either

- `shift` off all single options as you do and then copy the rest into the arrayref

  ```
  domains => [ @_ ];
  ```
- or pass an arrayref, which is a scalar, like in your second invocation and assign it

  ```
  domains => shift;
  ```

In both cases the `$self->{domains}` is going to be an arrayref.

On the other hand, consider nicely assigning arguments first

```
sub new { 
    my ($class, $server, $type, @domains) = @_;
    # ...
    my $self = { 
        # ...
        domains => \@domains
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

for the first invocation, or

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $server, $type, $rdomains) = @_;
    my $self = {
        # ...
        domains => $rdomains
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

for the second one. Since [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) returns its first argument we can directly `return` (for brevity).

Finally, you use the [indirect object notation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods) for calling the constructor.  In short, don't -- use

```
my $object = ClassName->new( ARGS );
```

See the link above for an official statement, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955172/what-is-indirect-object-notation-why-is-it-bad-and-how-does-one-avoid-it)

---

Please *always* run with [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html), as that saves a lot of headaches. I also strongly suggest to always use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) as it promotes all manner of good practices

```
# At the beginning of every program
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
```

Comment: Hey zdim, would i still need to include `bless $self, $class;` and `return $self;` after I set `my $self = {...}` ?

Comment: @user081608  Yes, by all means.  Setting `$self` merely populates a hashref in the program.  It is the `bless`-ing that makes `$self` an object of `$class`, and after that line `$self` "knows" what class it belongs to, you can call methods on it, etc. While `return`ing it is important for all kinds of uses.  I've added that for completeness, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify domains as a list, you need to do this:

```
sub new {
   $class = shift;
   $self = {
     server => shift,
     type => shift,
     domains => [ @_ ],
   };
   bless $self, $class;
   return $self;
}
```

That's because hashes cannot have non-scalar keys or values.

Either way, you are going to have to dereference that array ref when iterating through domains:

```
for my $domain (@{ $self->{domains} }){
     print "$domain\n";
 }
```